# Intersection -| of a named and a calculated coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I want to use the intersection of a named and a calculated coordinate, in other words the y-coordinate of a named coordinate but the x-coordinate of a calculated coordinate, such as the point Z below, which has

- the y-coordinate of X
- the x-coordinate of `($(A)!0.5!(B)$)`

But `(X -| $(A)!0.5!(B)$)` doesn't work... is there an alternative?

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0, minimum width=1mm}]
\node [dot] (A) at (0.5,0) {} node[below=0.1mm of A]{A};
\node [dot] (B) at (2,3) {} node[below=0.1mm of B]{B};
\node [dot] (X) at (0,5) {} node[below=0.1mm of X]{X};
\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw (X) -| ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
\node [dot] (Y) at (X -| B){} node[above=0.1mm of Y]{Y};
\coordinate(AB) at ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
\node [dot] (Z) at (X -| AB){} node[above=0.1mm of Z]{Z};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Didn't you already have an alternative yourself? (namely, naming the calculated coordinate first)

Comment: You are not using `positioning`(in a meaningful way) here. `\node [dot] (A) at (0.5,0) {} node[below=0.1mm of A]{A};` is the same as `\node[dot] (A) at (0.5,0) {} (A) node[below=0.1mm]{A};` the same as `\node[dot] (A) at (0.5,0) {}; \node[below=0.1mm] at (A) {A};` or better use `\coordinate` when it is a coordinate and not a node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved by surrounding `$(A)!0.5!(B)$` with braces.

With the original code, there is a small space between the dot and the line at `X`, `A` and `B`. This space is removed with the option `outer sep=0pt`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0, minimum width=1mm, outer sep=0pt}]
\node [dot] (A) at (0.5,0) {} node[below=0.1mm of A]{A};
\node [dot] (B) at (2,3) {} node[below=0.1mm of B]{B};
\node [dot] (X) at (0,5) {} node[below=0.1mm of X]{X};
\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw (X) -| ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
\node [dot] (Y) at (X -| B){} node[above=0.1mm of Y]{Y};
\node [dot] (Z) at (X -| {$(A)!0.5!(B)$}){} node[above=0.1mm of Z]{Z};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you! that helps; I was so close.

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle, fill=black, inner sep=0, minimum width=1mm, outer sep=0pt}]
\coordinate[dot, label=below:{A}] (A) at (0.5,0);
\coordinate[dot, label=below:{B}] (B) at (2,3);
\coordinate[dot, label=below:{X}] (X) at (0,5);
\draw (A) -- (B);
\draw (X) -| ($(A)!0.5!(B)$);
\coordinate[dot, label=below:{Y}] (Y) at (X-|B);
\path let \p1=($(A)!0.5!(B)$), \p2=(X) in coordinate[dot, label=above:{Z}] (Z) at (\x1,\y2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Dot line diagram]

Comment: @matexmatics solution is better as it does not mix the syntax as mine. My solution is an alternative, but I think it is better to use `\coordinate` when it is a coordinate - do not use empty nodes.

Comment: you can use `\coordinate` with styles?!?!?!? wow!

Comment: @JasonS: Yes - a TikZ coordinate is the same as a node(with a special shape and no content) `\node[shape=coordinate]{}`. The shape `coordinate` has no size, no `inner sep` or `outer sep` - that is of cause ruined when changing the shape. The advantage is more that the code is easier to read.